# How does one get that $1^3+2^3+3^3+4^3+\cdots=\frac{1}{120}$?

Tags: number-theory, summation, math-history, summation-method, ramanujan-summation

While watching interesting mathematics videos, I found one of the papers  of Srinivasa Ramanujan to G.H.Hardy in which he had written $1^3+2^3+3^3+4^3+\cdots=\frac{1}{120}$.

The problem is that every term on the left is more than $\frac{1}{120}$ yet the sum is $\frac{1}{120}$. How is that ???

I know that there are many and much more interesting things  presented by Ramanujan (like $1-1+1-1+1...=\frac{1}{2}$ and $1+2+3+4.....=\frac{-1}{12}$) but for now I am interested in the summation in the title.
Any idea/hint is heartily welcome. Thanks.

[Here is](https://youtu.be/jcKRGpMiVTw) the video I'm talking about.

Comment: The $\frac{-1}{12}$ summation has many more questions here and all the answers are relevant to this question. For example: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/633285/is-the-sum-of-all-natural-numbers-frac112

Comment: Definition of infinite sums vary

Comment: @Hugh, I know that there are many more questions already asked on -1/12. But I don't see any answer there which can give the answer of the question I have asked.

Comment: @ZelosMalum, How and to what extent??

Comment: @THELONEWOLF. By changing metrics and much else and to what extent? Infinitely much :) Might wanna look up p-adic numbers.

Comment: Should this perhaps be also tagged ([tag:ramanujan-sumation])? I am not familiar with this method myself, but [the tag-info](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/ramanujan-summation/info) and [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan_summation) provide some basic information.

Comment: This result is also mentioned in [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1883242). And perhaps you can find some other posts [about evaluating $\zeta(-3)$](http://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22zeta%28-3%29%22+120).

Comment: +1 for referring to a decent piece of exposition rather than the infamous-youtube-video-that-shall-not-be-named. (Although, even if I did not re-watch Mathologer's piece, I would think the answer to your question is explained there.)

Comment: @did the video was on the summation -1/12. After watching half of it I thought now I should move to MSE

Comment: http://karagila.org/2016/syntactic-t-rex-irregularized/

Comment: You wrote one of the sums wrong.  It should be $$1-1+1-1+\dots=\frac12$$

Comment: Yes, @SimpleArt,Thanks for pointing it. I have edited it

Comment: @AsafKaragila: I'm afraid I would disagree with your editing on the title. The question in the body shows that OP does not know what a Ramanujan Summation is. If one uses the title as what it is now, then the title does not match the spirit of the body.

Comment: @Jack: I know that *there is* such a thing as a Ramanujan sum, and if someone would have told me that $1^3+2^3+3^3+\ldots=\frac1{120}$, I would imagine that the result can be derived like that. But I don't know how is the Ramanujan summation is defined, its machinations or how to derive this equality. I don't see how using a term in the title makes the question any different.

Comment: @AsafKaragila It is a specific method to evaluating such sums.  Perhaps we should change the title to something more along the lines "How does one sum ...?"  The references in the body of the question should be fine enough.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: As I said in the previous comment, "The question in the body shows that *OP* does not know what a Ramanujan Summation is." And I think that is the reason why he/she asks "The problem is that every term on the left is more than $\frac{1}{120}$ yet the sum is $\frac{1}{120}$. How is that ???"  If *OP* knows such a concept, then he/she would not put the question in the body of the post in that way, would he/she?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think I have rediscovered it (after watching the video you linked and read wiki biography of Ramanujan).

Start with $$
\frac{1}{x+1} =1 -x +x^2 -x^3 +-\cdots, \quad |x| <1.
$$ and differentiate to get $$
-\frac{1}{(x+1)^2} =-1 +2x -3x^2 +4x^3 -+\cdots, \quad |x| <1. \\
\frac{2}{(x+1)^3} =2 \cdot 1 -3 \cdot 2x +4 \cdot 3 x^2 -+\cdots, \quad |x| <1. \\
-\frac{6}{(x+1)^4} =-3 \cdot 2 \cdot 1 +4 \cdot 3 \cdot 2x -5 \cdot 4 \cdot 3 x^2 +-\cdots, \quad |x| <1.
$$

Take a magic mushroom and, ignoring $|x| <1$, let us take $x=1$ in each one. $$
\frac{1}{2} =1 -1 +1 -1 +- \cdots \\
-\frac{1}{4} =-1 +2 -3 +4 -+ \cdots \\
\frac{1}{4} =2 \cdot 1 -3 \cdot 2 +4 \cdot 3 -+ \cdots \\
-\frac{3}{8} =-3 \cdot 2 \cdot 1 +4 \cdot 3 \cdot 2 -5 \cdot 4 \cdot 3 +- \cdots
$$ Or more formally, $$
\sum_{m=1}^\infty (-1)^{m+1} m =\frac{1}{4}. \\
\sum_{m=1}^\infty (-1)^{m+1} m (m+1) =\frac{1}{4}. \\
\sum_{m=1}^\infty (-1)^{m+1} m (m+1) (m+2) =\frac{3}{8}.
$$

But notice $$ \begin{align}
\sum_{m=1}^\infty (-1)^{m+1} m^2
=&\sum_{m=1}^\infty (-1)^{m+1} m (m+1) -\sum_{m=1}^\infty (-1)^{m+1} m \\
=&\frac{1}{4} -\frac{1}{4} =0.
\end{align}
$$ and $$ \begin{align}
\sum_{m=1}^\infty (-1)^{m+1} m^3
=&\sum_{m=1}^\infty (-1)^{m+1} m (m+1) (m+2) -3\sum_{m=1}^\infty (-1)^{m+1} m^2 -2\sum_{m=1}^\infty (-1)^{m+1} m \\
=&\frac{3}{8} -3 \cdot 0 -2 \cdot \frac{1}{4}
=-\frac{1}{8} \quad \quad \ldots \spadesuit
\end{align}
$$

On the other hand, $$
\zeta(-3) :=1^3 +2^3 +3^3 +\cdots \\
2^4 \zeta(-3) =2 \cdot 2^3 +2 \cdot 4^3 +2 \cdot 6^3 +\cdots \\
$$ Subtract them, aligning the 2nd, 4th, 6th term like Ramanjunan did in his notebooks (shown in the video). $$
-15 \zeta(-3) =1^3 -2^3 +3^3 -+\cdots \quad \quad \ldots \heartsuit
$$ $\heartsuit$ and $\spadesuit$ together give us: (Hold your breath.) $$
\sum_{m=1}^\infty m^3 =\frac{1}{120}.
$$

Recently I also found a proof of Riemann conjecture, but the answer box is too narrow for me to type all that down.

P.s. seriously, I think Ramanujan's effort is sort of finding an interpretation of divergent series so that they have a real value, while their manipulation to be still consistent to our usual notion of arithmetics: arranging, addition, expanding, etc.? 
Maybe this can be compared to the attempt to define quaternion as an extension of complex numbers, while inevitably discarding commutative law?

Comment: I'm absolutely fascinated that this came as a result of ignoring $|x|<1$ to allow $x=1$. How much of the work can be made valid by taking the limit as $x$ tends to $1$?

Comment: @Hugh If we rewrite it as $x\to1$, then we are regularizing the sum.  But any way you look at it, you are regularizing the result if you don't get $\infty$ as the answer.

Comment: And see [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1994136/alternative-analytic-continuation-to-zeta-not-giving-frac112-for-sum-of/1994162#1994162) about the invariance properties of those summation methods. cc @SimpleArt

Comment: I love the magic mushroom part.

Answer (score 9):

Let $f(x)=x^d$ for $d\geq 1$ then by [Euler–Maclaurin summation formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula) 
$$\sum_{k=1}^nf(x)=C+\int_0^n f(x) dx+\frac{f(n)}{2}+\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{B_{2k}}{(2k)!}f^{(2k-1)}(n)$$
where $B_n$ denotes the $n$-th [Bernoulli number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_number).

In his theory of [Divergent Series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan_summation),  Ramanujan "identified" $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}f(x)$ with $C$. Note that $C$ is zero if $d$ is even and it is $-\frac{B_{d+1}}{d+1}$ if $d$ is odd. So for $d=1$ we get $-\frac{1}{12}$ and for $d=3$ we obtain $\frac{1}{120}$.

Comment: So: don't call $1/120$ the "sum"... instead call it the "Euler-Maclarin remainder".  Then beginners (like Mr WOLF) will not be confused by it.

Answer (score 6):

Below is the derivation of the following equality:

> $$\zeta(-s)=\frac1{1-2^{1+s}}\lim_{r\to1^-}\left(\underbrace{r\cdot\frac d{dr}r\cdot\frac d{dr}\dots r\cdot\frac d{dr}}_s\frac{-1}{1+r}\right)$$

---

Notice that if we have

$$\zeta(s)=1+\frac1{2^s}+\frac1{3^s}+\frac1{4^s}+\dots$$

$$\eta(s)=1-\frac1{2^s}+\frac1{3^s}-\frac1{4^s}+\dots$$

then, when they are absolutely convergent, we get the functional equation:

$$\begin{align}\zeta(s)&=1+\frac1{2^s}+\frac1{3^s}+\frac1{4^s}+\dots\\\eta(s)&=1-\frac1{2^s}+\frac1{3^s}-\frac1{4^s}+\dots\\\hline\zeta(s)-\eta(s)&=2\left(\ \ \frac1{2^s}\qquad\ \ +\frac1{4^s}+\dots\right)\\&=2^{1-s}\left(1+\frac1{2^s}+\frac1{3^s}+\frac1{4^s}+\dots\right)\tag{factored out $2^s$}\\&=2^{1-s}\zeta(s)\end{align}$$

Solving for $\zeta(s)$, we get

$$\zeta(s)=\frac1{1-2^{1-s}}\eta(s)$$

And since these are analytic functions, this holds for all $s$.

As a somewhat elementary method, we can evaluate the $\eta(s)$ as follows, which converges for all $s$.

$$\eta(s)=\lim_{r\to1^-}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n+1}r^n}{n^s}$$

And thus, we have ourselves left with

$$\eta(-3)=\lim_{r\to1^-}\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^{n+1}r^nn^3=-\frac18$$

which may be done by manipulating the geometric series:

$$\frac{-1}{1+r}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^{n+1}r^n$$

$$r\cdot\frac d{dr}\frac{-1}{1+r}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^{n+1}nr^n\\\vdots$$

$$\underbrace{r\cdot\frac d{dr}r\cdot\frac d{dr}\dots r\cdot\frac d{dr}}_k\frac{-1}{1+r}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^{n+1}n^kr^n$$

Which then yields the desired result $\zeta(-3)=\frac1{120}$.

So, succinctly, we end up with the following form for the zeta function whenever $s\in\mathbb N,\ s>0$:

> $$\zeta(-s)=\frac1{1-2^{1+s}}\lim_{r\to1^-}\left(\underbrace{r\cdot\frac d{dr}r\cdot\frac d{dr}\dots r\cdot\frac d{dr}}_s\frac{-1}{1+r}\right)$$

which isn't terribly difficult to work out.  Just a lot of quotient rule going on in there.  If $s=0$, we have

$$\zeta(0)=\frac1{1-2^{1+0}}\lim_{r\to1^-}\left(\frac1{1+r}\right)=-\frac12$$

---

Some values worked out for you:

$$\zeta(-1)=\frac1{1-2^{1+1}}\lim_{r\to1^-}\left(r\cdot\frac d{dr}\frac{-1}{1+r}\right)=-\frac13\lim_{r\to1^-}\left(\frac{r}{(1+r)^2}\right)=-\frac1{12}$$

$$\zeta(-2)=\frac1{1-2^{1+2}}\lim_{r\to1^-}\left(r\cdot\frac d{dr}r\cdot\frac d{dr}\frac{-1}{1+r}\right)=-\frac17\lim_{r\to1^-}\left(r\cdot\frac d{dr}\frac{r}{(1+r)^2}\right)\\=-\frac17\lim_{r\to1^-}\left(\frac{r-r^2}{(1+r)^3}\right)=0$$

$$\zeta(-3)=\frac1{1-2^{1+3}}\lim_{r\to1^-}\left(r\cdot\frac d{dr}r\cdot\frac d{dr}r\cdot\frac d{dr}\frac{-1}{1+r}\right)=-\frac1{15}\lim_{r\to1^-}\left(r\cdot\frac d{dr}\frac{r-r^2}{(1+r)^3}\right)\\=-\frac1{15}\left(\frac{r-4r^2+r^3}{(1+r)^4}\right)=\frac1{120}$$

Comment: :D Upvotes and downvotes, appears someone can't quite choose lol.  XD The notifications are too much XD

Comment: I agree, It seems that people are confused. By the way you got +1 by me.

Comment: @THELONEWOLF. Lol, it was quite comical watching my notifications flash.

Comment: Pretty much same here. I have got 12 upvote and 7 downvotes.

Comment: @THELONEWOLF. Lol, I meant that someone was upvoting and un-upvoting my question repeatedly

Comment: Oops you are not as lucky as me.

Comment: Do you think my question is exact duplicate??

Comment: @THELONEWOLF. Probably because I got to this question late.  And since this is all chat, I'll move it to the chat if you don't mind.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49891/discussion-between-simple-art-and-the-lone-wolf).

Answer (score 3):

> The problem is that every term on the left is more than $\frac{1}{120}$ yet the sum is $\frac{1}{120}$. How is that ???

To answer the question directly: [Ramanujan summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan_summation) is a technique invented by the mathematician Srinivasa Ramanujan for assigning a value to *divergent* infinite series. It is well explained in the linked Wikipedia article.

Comment: I like how the first few lines down after the divergent series stuff basically answers the question.

Answer (score 1):

When you define a series like  $1^3+2^3+3^3+4^3+...+n^3$ you have a specific definition in mind for How to compute this series and How to take the limit as $n$ tends to infinity.

Ramanujan is using a different definition for what it means to compute this series. That definition allows for properties like the sum of numbers being equal to a value smaller than every term.

Comment: This seems more comment-worthy.  Perhaps you could expand a bit more on how to actually compute the series?